# Is there way to destructure in reducer new added object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I'm learning redux on app, that when you click day in calendar, it show form.
After submit redux should take data from this form and and put in state like this date:[obj, obj, obj]. -> // date == activeDate

I can't destructure date, so it mutates and I have only one object in date array each time I hit submit.

```
    case SET_DATE:
       return {
         ...state,
          activeDate: action.payload.date
       }
    case ADD_CUT:
    const {date, name, hour, minute, kind} = action.payload
        return {
            ...state,
            appointments: {
                ...state.appointments,
                [date]: [
                       // here i need to destructure sth like
                       // ...state.appointments.date
                       // or state.appointments.activeDate
                    {
                        name: name,
                        hour: hour,
                        minute: minute,
                        kind: kind
                    }
                ]
            }
    }
```

How I can destructure it? Or maybe I should take data in different way?

Comment: Is your state.appointments an array? And if it is array, do you want to add an item by the values in  action.payload?

Comment: state.appointments should be object, when i click day, and submit it should get  (clicked date): [{obj}]. If i add another object to this day by submit it should be  (clicked date): [{obj}, {newObject}] etc.

Comment: Can you give an an example of your state with data?

Comment: `state={
      activeDate: "20-12-2019",
      appointments: {
          "20-12-2019": [
                {name, time, kind}, {name, time, kind},
            ],
          "14-10-2018": [
                {name, time, kind}, {name, time, kind}, {name, time, kind},
            ]
      }
}`

Comment: I think it would be far easier to make  appointments an array,  and add the items there. Keep it simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would keep the appointments in an array, and simply add new appointment to it like this:

```
case ADD_CUT:
    const {date, name, hour, minute, kind} = action.payload;
   return {
       ...state,
       appointments: [
           ...state.appointments,
               {
                   date,
                   name,
                   hour,
                   minute,
                   kind
               }
          ]
  }
```

Comment: Yea it will work but i wanted data structure like:
appointments: { "20-12-2018":[{name, hour, minute, kind}, another obj from intput, ...],]}

Comment: @KamilDulęba better to use an array here, why do you want  to keep an object?

Comment: I tought, that this way when I wanna render appointments added to 
specific day, I will just do state.appointments.{date chosen on calendar}.map
But i think youre right, theres no reason to make life harder. I will use your structure and just filter it when comes to render. Thanks for help.